# $G$ is a group. Prove that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is bijective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

$G$ is a group and $f: G\to G$ is defined by $f(x)=x^{-1}$. Prove $f$ is bijective.

---

I know how to prove injectivity, I need to show that if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=b$. But I don't think it's enough to show that $a^{-1}=b^{-1}$, is it?

Also for surjectivity, I must come up with a $y$ such that $f(x)=y$ if whatever that $y$ is equals $x$.

Help?

Comment: Look at $(\mathbb Z, +, 0)$ or $(\mathbb Q^\ast, \cdot, 1)$. Anything seen there? Can you prove it?

Comment: Can you prove the inverse of an element is unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a^{-1} = b^{-1}$, multiply on the right on both sides by $b$ to get

$$a^{-1} b = b^{-1} b = e$$

Now multiply on the left by $a$ to find

$$a a^{-1} b = a e \implies b = a$$

establishing injectivity.

---

For surjectivity, you need to let $y \in G$ be arbitrary and cook up an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$; that is, we need to find an $x$ so that

$$x^{-1} = y$$

Can you think of an element $x$ satisfying this?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Prove $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a \quad \forall\ a\in G$ and then proceed using the definiton of a group.

Answer (score 0):

Another hint or exercise that helped me is to prove that:

$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1} \quad \forall a,b \in G$

Answer (score 0):

To prove $f$ is bijective it is enough to exhibit an inverse for $f$.

But this is easy because $f$ is its own inverse: $f(f(x))=(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$.